# Visual studio, intellisense and custom compiler settings

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, compiler-construction, code-completion

Please excuse me if this question is inappropriate, I switched to windows together with my linux code which is based on c++11 so I have 2 options, to change the compiler or rewrite my code, I'm prety sure I won't rewrite all the code but replace MSVC "C" compiler with something better like clang++ or g++.
But I'm unsure whether this will broke intellisense of visual studio and what can I do about that?
I would like to have both functionlaities, c++11 and good code completion in visual studio.

can you recommend what actions/compilers(other stuff) to take before struggling with new compilers and code completion settings?
I'm also unsure whether all that will work anyway.. thanks.

Comment: I *think* that the IntelliSense in VS is not using the actual VC++ compiler, but another library. And even if it did use the VC++ compiler, using another compiler for actually *building* the application wouldn't mess with IntelliSense, as the editor (and its IntelliSense) and building are completely orthogonal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg these are good news, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to change compiler? Visual Studio 2013 supports (most of) C++11 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx .

Comment: @WojtekSurowka  because of prebuilt gtkmm libraries which are built for msvc 100 (no c++11) or mingw which does support c++11, so I'm trying to make some mixture here whithout trying to build gtk+ which is so hard if not imposible on windows.